# "Undefined" when passing data to JavaScript from Android

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I'm using this code but the value said "undefined" can anyone point me the problem?

this is my java class codes

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(com.frux.web.R.layout.activity_main);
    String value = "Isiah";
    WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web1);
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    web.loadUrl("javascript:setValue(\""+ value +"\")");


}
```

and this is my webpage codes

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

Whats your Name?
<input id="name" value="" />
<button onclick = "setValue()">Submit</button>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
function setValue(value){
var myValue = value;
document.getElementById("name").value = myValue;

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I also try this one

```
web.loadUrl("javascript:setValue('"+ value +"')");
```

any thoughts will be highly appreciated

I used the codes in this HTML codes and its display nothing unlike the other codes above that I post.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<head>


<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript">  

function setValue(amount1)
{
    myValue = amount1;
    document.getElementById("amount").value = myValue;
  }

function rand ( n )
{
    document.getElementById("orderRefId").value =  ( Math.floor ( Math.random ( ) * n + 1 ) );
}



</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="rand(200000);setValue();">
        <!-- 
            Note: https://www.pesopay.com/b2c2/eng/payment/payForm.jsp for live payment URL
                  https://test.pesopay.com/b2cDemo/eng/payment/payForm.jsp for test payment URL
        -->
        <form method="POST" name="frmPayment" action="https://test.pesopay.com/b2cDemo/eng/payment/payForm.jsp">
        <table>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Order Reference No. (your reference number for every transaction that has transpired):</td> 
            <td><input type="text" id="orderRefId" name="orderRef" value="Test-001"/></td>
        </tr>   
        <tr>
            <td>Amount:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="amount" id="amount" value=""/></td>

        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Currency Code - "608" for Philippine Peso, "840" for US Dollar:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="currCode" value="608"/></td>
        </tr>   
        <tr>
            <td>Language:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="lang" value="E"/></td>
        </tr>   
        <tr>
            <td>Merchant ID (the merchant identification number that was issued to you - merchant IDs between test account and live account are not the same):</td> 
            <td><input type="text" name="merchantId" value="18056869"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>    
            <td>Redirect to a URL upon failed transaction:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="failUrl" value="http://www.yahoo.com?flag=failed"/></td>
        </tr>   
        <tr>
            <td>Redirect to a URL upon successful transaction:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="successUrl" value="http://www.google.com?flag=success"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Redirect to a URL upon canceled transaction:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="cancelUrl" value="http://www.altavista.com?flag=cancel"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Type of payment (normal sales or authorized i.e. hold payment):</td> 
            <td><input type="text" name="payType" value="N"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>    
            <td>Payment Method - Change to "ALL" for all the activated payment methods in the account, Change to "BancNet" for BancNet debit card payments only, Change to "GCASH" for GCash mobile payments only, Change to "CC" for credit card payments only:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="payMethod" value="ALL"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>    
            <td>Remark:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="remark" value="Asiapay Test"/></td>
        </tr>
        <!--<tr>    
            <td>Redirect:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="redirect" value="1"/></td>
        </tr>-->
        <tr>
            <td></td>
        </tr>   

        <input type="submit" value="Submit">




        </tbody>
        </table>    


        </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well you're not passing any value for the `value` argument of `setValue()`, hence it's undefined.

Comment: what do you mean? can you give me an idea for what you saying?

Comment: `setValue()` expects a parameter to be passed, `value`. It is being called by the button click, but no parameter is being passed - i.e. you are calling the function with no parameters, via just `setValue()`

Comment: can you please give me any link or can you please help me to do what you trying to point?

Comment: or can you tell me what is missing is my code? it will be my pleasure then.

Comment: It's impossible for me to know what you should pass to the function - I'm just pointing out that, currently, you're passing nothing. Perhaps @Alex Orlov's answer will help.

Comment: I already try that codes but still undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your passed value in double quotes:

```
web.loadUrl("javascript:setValue(\""+value+"\")");
```

I got this! When you call `loadUrl` for the second time the page has not loaded yet. The solution would be attaching your `setValue` call to `window.onload` event:

```
super.loadUrl("javascript:window.onload = function(){setValue(\"haha\");};");
```

This code loads 'haha' into input correctly.

Comment: w0w great tkanks a lot man! but why its automatically put the value in textbox with calling the setValue function.

Comment: because that's what your `setValue` function does.

Comment: it is still undefined when I call the function setValue() using onLoad or onClick.

Comment: are you passing an argument to setValue? because in your question's code you don't

Comment: can you please point me what I'm missing to make the setValue() function can be Call using onClick or onLoad in my Web Page.

Comment: `<button onclick = "setValue()">Submit</button>` this will try calling setValue without arguments. you should call it using the argument you want - setValue(value) or setValue("some string")

Comment: please take a look from what I post above a while ago. big thnx

Comment: Well, it's like a whole new question man... And in your body's onload you're calling setValue WITHOUT a parameter just like I told you several times already.

Comment: I edited it to this <body onLoad="setValue(myValue);"> but it display nothing

Comment: and what do you think myValue is when you're calling this function? there a var named myValue but it's local to setValue function and is undefined wherever else.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your value in a single quotes like so

```
 web.loadUrl("javascript:setValue('"+ value +"')");
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue when trying to access the DOM before it was ready. devmilles.com's solution worked but I spent a little more time experimenting.

Both of

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',
    function(){setValue('haha');}, false);");

webView.loadUrl("javascript:window.addEventListener('load',
    function(){setValue('haha');}, false);");
```

worked for me, but attaching the event to `document` instead of `window` did not. [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded), where supported, responds slightly faster than [`load`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/load).

Additionally, it turns out that `WebViewClient` has always had an [`onPageFinished()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageFinished%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29) event, which appears to work like the `load` event

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl("javascript:setValue('haha');");
    }
});
```

Lastly, I could emulate the behaviour with

```
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
        if (progress == 100) {
            view.loadUrl("javascript:setValue('haha');");
        }
    }
});
```

but I see no reason to use that over the `WebViewClient` approach (they may or may not be equivalent).

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing same problem.But the issue is resolved using below way.

```
     String testValue="abcdedfg";
    String value = "\'"+testValue+"\'";
    web.loadUrl("javascript:setValue(\""+value+"\")");
```